# check username and password from Twitter account in android

Tags: android, twitter

> hello expert
>   i need to know that how can i match username and password from Twitter account?
>   is any jar file are there?
>   and tell me how can i use it?

Comment: should use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) and there ar tutos like that just search http://androidforums.com/introductions/218621-twitter4j-oauth-android-simple.html

Comment: please tell me how do it programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[use this](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html) to get properly

Answer (score 1):

there's already a question well answered here :
[Twitter Login Authentication in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268020/twitter-login-authentication-in-android)

give it a look!

Comment: can you give me entire example