# Android development: SSO on Twitter

Tags: android, twitter, android-twitter

I'm having trouble in finding information regarding on how to implement Twitter login with SSO (Single Sign On) for an Android Application, is there any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3268440/493749):

> heres is a excellent example to implement **OAuth for Twitter in
>   Android**
>
> http://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth by Brion Emde
>
> heres the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25o0b2aEw0E)

Comment: Thanks for answering Chris, but I think that we are talking about two different things:

If I'm not wrong (there are high chances that yes :p) SSO allows me to: if a user has the Twitter app account configured on his Android Phone I don't have to ask him to login since I will use the session configured on his cell.

The link that you posted is about to how to do a OAuth login, that would be the next step if I can't do SSO.

Maybe I wasn't clear, but for example Facebook has SSO docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/sso/), but I haven't found the same for Twitter.

Comment: Ah. There is Twitter SSO for iOS, but not yet (at least from Twitter's dev team) for Android.