# Twitter Logging and not redirecting to app and How to Use CALLBACK URL

Tags: android, logging, twitter

As I am trying to integrate twitter in my android app. But its Logging through browser and how to call back to my app. Its redirecting to callback URL that i specified in

```
apps.twitter.com/app/•••••••
```

As i tried, different URLs in my app callback URL.

```
twitter app://connect
app://twitter
```

and intent in manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare callback in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

your callback url :

```
public static final String TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-twitter://twitterlogin";
```

your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="twitterlogin"
                android:scheme="x-oauthflow-twitter" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
```

Comment: Error : "The Webpage at this url is not found" and any changes in twitter app callback url..?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22543102/twitter-integration-in-android-using-twitter4j-4-0-1

Comment: i have a doubt in androidmanifest.xml in data element what should be be the andoird:host its a app name or what\

Comment: what is your callback url? if your callback url is "x-oauthflow-twitter://twitterlogin" , then "twitterlogin" will be your android:host and "x-oauthflow-twitter" will be android:scheme.

Comment: my app name is sample twitterlogs then what will be android:host. Please let me know that?

Comment: <activity android:name="com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook.HelloFacebookSampleActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                <data android:scheme="oauth" android:host="t4jsample"/>
            </intent-filter>
           
        </activity>

Comment: Although host is optional, for me, the callback must have scheme and host x-oauthflow-twitter://twitterlogin