# Login in application using facebook or twitter account

Tags: android, facebook

I'm building an mobile application in android. I want to know how can i log in using my facebook or twitter account. 
Thank you!

Comment: Try: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1

Comment: please do some research before asking questions, there are plenty of tutorials for this and those platforms offer large documentations too. don´t be lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire tutorial how to implement User Authentication:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1

For Twitter:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

[Twitter Login Authentication in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268020/twitter-login-authentication-in-android)

::EDIT

This is a very good tutorial for Twitter:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

::END

You probably what to know a bit about OAuth:

http://oauth.net/